# Need help with contingency table for predicting signup result

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to calculate the number of people in a sample of the population who fit certain criteria.

For example, let's say we have a population of 1,000 people. We also know the following about the general population:

18% smoke cigarettes
4.3% are diabetics
29% exercise more than twice a week
How would we estimate how many of the 1,000 people in our sample population do not smoke and are not diabetic and don't exercise more than twice a week?

We can assume that smokers, diabetics and exercisers occur in equal proportion (eg. assume 4.3% of smokers and non-smokers are diabetic)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a contengency table for three events.

The information

> We can assume that smokers, diabetics and exercisers occur in equal
>   proportion (eg. assume 4.3% of smokers and non-smokers are diabetic)

i haven´t used so far for the table.

I hope it helps.[image]